# Google App Engine can't run dev_appserver (500/301 error & appengine.api Import Error)

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

My team and I are looking to deploy a python app engine project locally using dev_appserver. The application seems to be working when we deploy to GCP and access as an end user would, but when deploying via dev_appserver and python main.py, we are seeing errors in both the browser and in the terminal:

When deploying via dev_appserver, we see the following:

'Standard' 500 HTTP error in Chrome Browser:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/vIC7weu]

Also see a 301 error in the command line:
[image]

When deploying via python main.py, we see the following:

Import Error: No module named appengine.api
[image]

Appreciate the time reading through this post and hope to get this resolved as everything else I've read on other SO posts/forums elsewhere has not provided any help.

Thanks all.

Comment: It's not obvious from your images but `dev_appserver` does not work with Python 3.x. Is that a possible issue? It's a good practice to copy text (rather than images) in questions (you can paste text within three backticks to mark it up as code. `dev_appserver` emulates App Engine's runtime services so I think this is why you can't use `appengine.api` from `python main.py` (as this is a purely local server).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DazWilkin, we're running on a Python2.7 runtime so I don't believe that 3.x compatibility would be the issue. We're able to use dev_appserver when testing the application on my Macbook but when attempting on my colleagues' Windows machine, we see this issue... very odd.

Comment: Aha! Then it's probable that there's an issue with the `dev_appserver` on Windows. I recommend you file an issue with Cloud Support or perhaps Google's Issue Tracker (https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/). Please include logs (not images) in either case and be sure to provide details about the OS, `gcloud info`, Python runtime etc.